# Conditional filtering based on textfield/selection inputs - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a JSON object with cards and their attributes. What i'm doing is making a search function that will parse the JSON based on the choices the user makes in the form.

The cards are not all of the same type. Some have attributes that others don't. For example one can have "cost" but the other simply provides "income".

Here is my code

```
        <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="card in cards
             | filter: { faction_name: searchHouse } 
             | filter: { name : searchTitle } 
             | filter: { text : searchText }
             | filter: { type_code : searchType }
             | filter: { cost : searchCost}
             | filter: { strength : searchStrength }
             | filter: { income : searchGold }
             | filter: { initiative : searchInitiative }
             | filter: { claim : searchClaim }
             | filter: { reserve : searchReserve }
             | limitTo: quantity 
             | orderBy: 'name' ">
             {{card.name}} - {{card.faction_name}}
            </li>
        <ul>
```

As i said, the cards may not have the same attributes. So if i search for the "gold" option

```
<input type="number" ng-model="searchGold" placeholder="Gold" min="0" class="form-control"/>
```

I can no longer search for other cards that don't have the particular attribute. I guess an empty string of that is always filtered even if i delete the value from the textfield.

I considered something of

```
filter: (hasGold || '') && cost : searchCost"
```

That would be set to true or false depending on what "type_code" i get from an earlier input.

I'm not sure how to do this, and the code is a bit messy already with so many filters that are not into the controller.

My sole Controller is the following

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, cardsFactory) {

    Init();

    function Init(){
        console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");
        //$scope.data = {};
        cardsFactory.get().then(function(data) {
        $scope.cards = data;
        });

        $scope.houses=['Targaryen', 'Stark', 'Lannister', 'Martell', 'Greyjoy', 'Tyrell', 'The Night\'s Watch', 'Baratheon', 'Neutral'];
        $scope.types=['Character', 'Location', 'Event', 'Attachment', 'Plot']; 
        $scope.actions=['Military', 'Intrigue', 'Power'];
        $scope.quantity = 30;
    }

});
```

So to sum up : I want to get certain inputs from a form. Depending on which are selected, i want to run the appropriate filters. Some filter though, can only be triggered if a certain input has been selected.

How can i implement such logic in my controller?

**UPDATE** Yes, the whole thing has been moved into the controller but the problem persists. I have to deal with "" field now instead of undentified.

Answer (score 0):

If you move all filter criterias under one JSON object, like :

```
$scope.myFilter = {
   searchHouse: '',
   searchTitle: '',
   searchText: ''
};
```

then you can create custom filter and pass $scope.myFilter object as param

```
ng-repeat="card in cards | myMagicGoesHere:myFilter"
```

and filter

```
.filter('myMagicGoesHere', function () {
  return function (items, myFilter) {
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      // do some filtering magic
      if (magic is true) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit more on the first part, about the scope?  Say the user inserts "5" and i bind it to SearchGold in my input, how will i pass it to the filter myMagicGoesHere so i scan the items?

Comment: update input to use 'myFIlter.searchGold', like  <input type="number" ng-model="myFilter.searchGold" placeholder="Gold" min="0" class="form-control"/> and so on for all search inputs/selects/datePickers. Inside your custom filter console.log(myFilter)  you will see all values coming. in for cycle compare every item with search criteria and add to filtered only necessary